# Email with HTML-body loss

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchange-server, html-email

I'm developing a newsletter subsystem.
The user enters a newsletter content in HTML-editor and sends an email to the list of his customers.
This is an ASP.NET application. The mail server is MS Exchange.

The problem is that real letters with pretty complex html don't reach recipients. Since test email sending works just fine. Moreover if we take a single recipient first few letters arrive and then they just don't come. If we try another address it will work for few times, and then stop arriving again. Junk folder is empty. server logs are empty. No errors. Emails just disappear without a trace.

Here is my code (simplified and changed a little).

Email sending code:

```
Mailer mailer = new Mailer();

foreach(ClientAddress address in addresses) {
    mailer.SendEmail(address.Mail, address.Consultant.Email, newsletter.Topic, newsletter.Content);
}
```

Mailer:

```
public class Mailer {

    public virtual void SendEmail(string toAddress, string replyTo, string subject, string text) {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(Globals.Settings.Mail.SmtpClientAddress);
        message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(replyTo));
        message.From = new MailAddress(toAddress);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = text;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(Globals.Settings.Mail.SmtpServer, Globals.Settings.Mail.SmtpPort);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Globals.Settings.Mail.SmtpClientName, Globals.Settings.Mail.SmtpClientPassword);
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Mailing configuration:

```
<mail
    server="exchange.server.com"
    port="25"
    clientAddress="user@exchange.server.com"
    clientName="user@exchange.server.com"
    clientPassword="***" />
```

I heard that emails with html body can be blocked by mail servers. 
How to overcome this? How services like http://mailchimp.com/ solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think it depends on the rate you send these emails and content. Your emails may be blocked because your smtp server has been blacklisted or the recipients email server is blocking them if they are flagged as spam. I would recommend you use a 3rd party service like [SendGrid](http://SendGrid.com) if you want to send bulk emails

Comment: Thank you for response! It seems like rate really played its role here. But are there any tricks to overcome this? How SendGrid works this out? What if I would like to start a service like SendGrid myself? Any ideas...

Comment: SendGrid is very easy to set up. All you have to do is create an account and then configure your SMTP settings with the SendGrid details. The SendGrid .NET SDK is excellent. Make sure you upvote me if you are happy with the answer :)

Comment: I see, there is only one cons, we have to pay for this )) My customer would be happy with in-house solution. Everything already works fine, except this obstacle. I will be really appreciated for advices how to overcome it.